# variance of the difference of two independent variables is the sum of variances

Tags: statistics, data-science, data-analysis

It is said that variance of the difference of two independent variables is the sum of variances (topic - Confidence intervals. Two means. Independent samples)

I tried to experiment with small dataset of two variables. i found that sum of variance of 2 independent variable is not equal to variance of difference. the experiment is below:-

- 1. new york apple price [$3.80, $3.76, $3.87, $3.99, $4.02, $4.25,$4.13, $3.98]
     its variance = 0.027

2. LA apple price - [$3.02, $3.22, $3.24, $3.02, $3.06, $3.15, $3.81, $3.44], variance =  0.071
3. Their difference in prices = [0.78, 0.54, 0.63, 0.97, 0.96, 1.10, 0.32, 0.54] - variance = 0.0715

sum of LA apple price variance and NY apple price variance = 0.098 which not equal to variance of difference = 0.0715

can someone explain me why is it so please?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons:

1. The sample sizes are too small for the sample variances you calculated to be good approximations to the true variances of the underlying random variables.
2. The two random variables you chose are not independent.

I think both of these are at play here. You could try obtaining larger samples from two random variables that by common sense really should be independent, or simulate some data with a random number generator instead.